# JQuery Timer for Matches

Tags: jquery, timer

I would like to bulid a Timer (with minutes from 1 - 90 with start and stop)for a soccer match of my local team. How could i do that with JQuery? any ideas?
i couldnt find anything related.

thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)**.

```
var counter = 0;
var intervalID = setInterval(incrFun, 60000 );

function incrFun()
{
    if ( counter == 90 )
    {
        counter = 0;
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        return;
    }
    // do your timer related cal here
    counter ++;
}
```